# Mask web application ipaddress:port with domain name

Tags: server, dns, subdomain, web-hosting, cloudflare

I have a node js web application running on static ipaddress with port 4000. I can access my application on the internet successfully using port forwarding in router, now I want to mask my public ipaddress+port with a domain name. By that, I have obtained a domain name in freenom and use cloudflare to create DNS record, it went smooth if my web application is running in port 80 and I can't change it to 4000, port 80 is already occuppied in our local server. What will I do to achieve my goal?

This is my CloudFlare DNS record
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Cloudflare by default can proxy HTTP/HTTPS on a list of standard ports ([source](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/network-ports)). See list below as of today.

If you would like to proxy on a different port (such as `4000`), then you should consider using [Cloudflare Spectrum](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/products/cloudflare-spectrum/) which is designed for this scenario. Alternatively, change your application so that it uses one of the supported ports below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you cant do port forwarding using dns an alternative solution is using a cloudflare tunnel inside your server and point your tunnel to port 4000 and add a cname record with the tunnel address

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).